# Why is phpMyAdmin showing wrong table names?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I noticed that in phpMyAdmin, if I look at `information_schema.tables`, all the `TABLE_NAME` fields show the wrong name.  For example, what should be **bins** is showing as **sql.php?table=bins&db=2018colors&token=e1317be0f3c71e76ef89257db23788af**

If I run in the command-line, I get the correct table names.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables;
```

Every row shows this same issue.  Maybe it's just something I don't understand about MySQL.  This is MariaDB 5.5.56 with phpMyAdmin 4.4.15.10 running on CentOS.  But I have another machine running an older version of XAMPP on macOS and it does not have this problem.